# What is happening here? [Wolfram]

Tags: computational-mathematics, wolfram-alpha

When I input:

$2^{a/b} = (2^a)^{1/b}$

Into [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E(a%2Fb)%20%3D%20(2%5Ea)%5E(1%2Fb)), it produces a very strange looking "implicit plot":

[image: Wolfram Alpha Implicit Plot]

I'm entirely sure what this means or what it's even trying to plot and how. I suspect it may be a bug, but I thought I'd ask in case anyone has an explanation.

Comment: It applies to all real numbers (except $b = 0$) so WA is trying to color *everything*. That makes it look distorted because it's hard for WA to color every single point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WolframAlpha output is ultimately generated by Mathematica. That particular plot is generated by a Mathematica command that looks like so:

```
ContourPlot[2^(a/b) == (2^a)^b^(-1), {a, -1.3, 1.3}, {b, -1.3, 1.3}]
```

While, $2^{a/b} = (2^a)^{1/b}$ is true for a lot of real $a$ and $b$, Mathematica evaluates this numerically and gets some small errors. You can see this using a command like so:

```
Table[2^(a/b) - (2^a)^b^(-1), {a, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2}, {b, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2}]
(* Out:
  {{6.66134*10^-16, 2.22045*10^-16, 2.22045*10^-16}, 
   {0., 0., 0.}, 
   {-2.13163*10^-14, -4.44089*10^-16, -4.44089*10^-16}}
*)
```

Of interest here is the fact that there are positive, negative and zero values. Thus, the `ContourPlot` command generates the crazy looking graph. This can be fixed in Mathematica using the `WorkingPrecision` option.